# Tool to delete browser history permanently

Tags: windows, web-browser, privacy

There are many tools for every Browser who deletes my surf-history. For Opera "[History-Eraser](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/history-eraser/?display=en)" is a useful tool. For Firefox you can use "Click&Clean". And there are enough other tools for all other browsers.

But the problem is, I don't know if these tools delete the History, Cookies etc. files permanently. So I'm worried that the deleted browsing-files and cookies could be restored with tools like "[recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva)".

So I would like to know if there is a tool or add-on (for example for Firefox) which deletes my Browser-History, Cookies, Trackers, browsing-cache etc. forever.

A useful tool is called "Secure Eraser", but it don't deletes my browser-history and cookie files.

Is there a tool or possibility to delete cache-files forever? I'm scared that the deleted browser-history could be recovered.

I'd like it to run on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Have you considered using an encrypted filesystem? It seems that any answer that you receive below may not completely solve your issue. By adding encryption, you make it far less likely that someone could access your history and cookies in the first place. This could be used in conjunction with answers to your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a toll that would do this alone, but you can delete the files yourself using [SysInternals SDelete](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897443.aspx) and a little batch file.

From its description on the website, it implements military level deletion:

> SDelete implements the Department of Defense clearing and sanitizing standard DOD 5220.22-M, to give you confidence that once deleted with SDelete, your file data is gone forever.

It also mentions

> Note that SDelete securely deletes file data, but not file names located in free disk space.

but the file name itself IMHO is not sensitive.

### Firefox

The Firefox history is stored in SQLite databases named `places.sqlite`. The directory should be `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\`. The following batch file deletes all databases securely.

```
@echo off
cd %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\
for /f %%p in ('dir /s /b places.sqlite') do SDelete "%%p"
pause
```

After the file is deleted, Firefox should still start up normally.

Comment: Similar approach can be applied for other browsers as long as you can identify all files and the files can be deleted without affecting the browser.

Answer (score -1):

Well that depends on who might be looking for that data. If it's just an average person or even an IT professional i think simply deleting is enough. But it's completely impossible to keep it from someone who is skilled enough to do that. But if you are really paranoid here is a software that i will recommend

[CyberScrub](http://www.cyberscrub.com/)

> .**This allows you to erase data using wipe methods that exceed
>   standards set by the United States Department of Defense for secure
>   file erasure.**

Comment: Could you explain "it's completely impossible to keep it from someone who is skilled enough"? CyberScrub seems to be a company. Which of their products offers the required functionality.

Comment: Yeah the CyberScrub Privacy Suite is the one i was talking abt. And yes it is impossible to delete the data see the data is stored in two places hardware and the software so i might just need a lot more than a 50$ software to delete everything that's is y people used to burn their hard disk instead of just erasing everything. Like you may have seen this in MR.ROBOT too the guy is the smartest hacker but still he fried his hard drives instead of erasing everything because it is possible to recover data even with a single file location.If you like to know more google a lot of resources are their

Comment: Well, that's a mystery. The German magazine c't has done some research on it. Even professional data rescue companies like Kroll Ontrack cannot recover hard disks that were securely erased.